# yarn hardhat verify --help error

Tags: etherscan, hardhat, verify

I'm trying to get help with the command `yarn hardhat verify --help`.
I get the following error

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ F:\Aleksey\Study\Blockchain\projects\hardhat-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\.bin\hardhat verify --help
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: Cannot find module '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-etherscan'
Require stack:
- F:\Aleksey\Study\Blockchain\projects\hardhat-simple-storage-fcc\hardhat.config.js
- F:\Aleksey\Study\Blockchain\projects\hardhat-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\hardhat\internal\core\config\config-loading.js
- F:\Aleksey\Study\Blockchain\projects\hardhat-simple-storage-fcc\node_modules\hardhat\internal\cli\cli.js       
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Aleksey\Study\Blockchain\projects\hardhat-simple-storage-fcc\hardhat.config.js:4:1)    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'F:\\Aleksey\\Study\\Blockchain\\projects\\hardhat-simple-storage-fcc\\hardhat.config.js',
    'F:\\Aleksey\\Study\\Blockchain\\projects\\hardhat-simple-storage-fcc\\node_modules\\hardhat\\internal\\core\\config\\config-loading.js',
    'F:\\Aleksey\\Study\\Blockchain\\projects\\hardhat-simple-storage-fcc\\node_modules\\hardhat\\internal\\cli\\cli.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

hardhat.config.js:

```js
// const env = require("hardhat");

require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-etherscan");
require("dotenv").config();

const GOERLI_RPC_URL = process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY;

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        goerli: {
            url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: 5,
        },
    },
    etherscan: {
        apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
    },
    solidity: "0.8.8",
};
```

I installed this module, its version is the latest, tried to roll back to `3.0.1` and `3.0.3`, nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```js
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");
```

instead of

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-etherscan");
```